# Gradle is not compiling using ndkBuild

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I have an android project configured in eclipse that works good with ant and ndk-build with some customized Android.mk and Application.mk files. I need to move them to Android Studio and I don't want to use CMake that comes with it, so I just want to keep my old .mk files. To do so I started with a simple hello world example with the following code:

Here the native-lib.cpp:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>

extern "C"
{

jstring Java_com_comscore_android_app_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
        JNIEnv* env,
        jobject /* this */) {
    std::string hello = "Hello from C++ lalalaaaaaa";
    return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
}
}
```

and here my gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.comscore"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            ndkBuild {
                arguments "NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=src/main/jni/Application.mk"
            }
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild{
        ndkBuild{
            path "src/main/jni/Android.mk"
        }
    }
...
}
```

Here the Android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := native-lib.cpp
LOCAL_MODULE    := native-lib


LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog

LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -fsigned-char -fexceptions -frtti -g -O0 -std=c++0x -std=gnu++0x 
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -fsigned-char -fexceptions -frtti -g -O0 -std=c++0x -std=gnu++0x 

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And finally the Application.mk:

```
APP_ABI := all
APP_STL := gnustl_static
```

But the C code is never compiled, could any body help me with this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the compilation errors.

Answer (score 0):

it was not compiling anything, that was the problem. Now I solved after cleaning up the build folder manually